# Play vimeo videos using android native player?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, video, vimeo

I am developing a website that makes use of vimeo and, for mobile devices, I want the video to be played using the phone's native player. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: No progress. Doesn't seem like it's possible with the current version of vimeo API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Answer (score 0):

**In android**

**First of all** . add io.vov.vitamio.widget package in your project .

**2.** Then define a videoview in your xml layout file ...

**3.** Then use this code in your java file. Make sure that you are importing packages available in vimeo package

```
 videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path)); 
 videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)); 
 videoView.requestFocus(); 
 videoView.start();
```

And its done.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify. This was a mobile web app, not a native app.

Comment: @JanshairKhan i want to develop in native app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520783/vimeo-video-play-in-android-native

Comment: Can provide link to import

Comment: @Rao's the path variable is link.

Comment: @JanshairKhan I am not able to play this video https://player.vimeo.com/video/49462103  i tried as per your guidline

Comment: @JanshairKhan It showing 'Sorry, this video cannot be played'

Comment: Another workaround is 

   webView1.loadData("<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+VIDEO_ID+"\" width=\"180px\" height=\"180px\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>", "text/html", "utf-8");