# Embedding Vimeo videos in a fragment in an android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, vimeo, vimeo-android

I have been searching looooot without really finding much about embedding Vimeo Videos in a fragment in an android app.

Answers suggested it was necessary to have a Vimeo Pro Account, use iframe or to use some external player or inofficial library etc.

As I am still quite new to Android Development, I didnt manage to implement any these suggestions into a working solution.

So if there are any other people being new to this and wanting to embed a vimeo video within a fragment in the simplest form, I wana share my code for embedding a vimeo video within a fragment that contains a TextView and an ImageView. ScrollView is necessary, cause otherwise when I rotate it, my imageView gets shrinked.

The only thing i note is that the webview loads a bit slow, so for a short while, only my other Views are displayed, so suggestions on improvements and best-practices are more than welcome.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <WebView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="PUT_TEXT"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

      <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:gravity="bottom"
       android:paddingTop="0dp"
       android:src="@drawable/PUT_IMAGE_HERE"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/PUT_IMAGE_HERE" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My Fragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

   public WebView webView;

   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
       webView.setInitialScale(1);
       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
       webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
       webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
       webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
       DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
       ((WindowManager)getContext()
                   .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                   .getDefaultDisplay()
                   .getMetrics(displaymetrics);

       int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
       int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
       Log.e("WebView Log", width + "-" + height);
       String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=high-dpi\" /> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)\" href=\"hdpi.css\" /></head> <body style=\"background:white;margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe style=\"background:white;\" width=' "+width+"' height='"+height/2+"' src=\""+"YOUR VIMEO URL"+"\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";

       webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://vimeo.com", data_html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
   }


   @Nullable
   @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_exercise, container, false);      
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I'd like to get some best-practice advise, plus I am not sure if its normal, but my webview loads a bit slow (just clarified it above), so at first one can only see textview and imageview

Comment: plus, I had such a hassle finding anything on vimeo video embedding, so this might help some other newbies like me

Comment: follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348