# Unity vimeo sdk streaming not work on android

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo, vimeo-android

I get the sdk from here, https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk
but when I build a single scene into android Huawei tab, the audio seems working including seeking but not the video.

[image]

Comment: See :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with Tengku [on GitHub](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/18), it seems like this is an issue with Unity's native `VideoPlayer` and not the Vimeo SDK as the streaming works on other devices/platforms. Feedback should be sent to the Unity team directly.