# Unity Vimeo Player not working on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo

I'm using **Vimeo** **Unity SDK** and a *REST API* that sends me back a *video url*, I tried to use `VimeoPlayer.PlayVideo(url)`  method but it doesn't work on mobile, on editor it works fine, the video is not played and I get no errors, also the method is wrapped on a coroutine. If someone has a solution I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information? Unity version, Vimeo plugin version, what android device and OS version?

Unity's native Video Player is not good across platforms. People have been having [quite](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/27) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814562/unity-vimeo-sdk-streaming-not-work-on-android) [few](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/27) [issues](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/52). I'd recommend using an alternative video decoder like [AVPro Video](http://renderheads.com/product/avpro-video/), which supports adaptive playback and is important for mobile devices like Android.

Comment: Thanks Casey, I'll give a try to AVPro and tell you how it goes.