# I want to play vimeo videos using vimeo API in android studio

Tags: vimeo-api, vimeo-android

There are several posts on this topic.

I tried the Vimeo networking example app from GitHub and Vimeo Deeplink, but none of them worked.

Everytime, I get an error like `URL misconfigured`.

**See below screenshot:**

[image: See the screenshot]

I don't know which is the right-way to proceed. I need to know how the URL is formed using the APIs.

Comment: See :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved the issue