# Can I use Vimeo native video streaming on android native instead if Webview when not using PRO account?

Tags: android, webview, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have tried searching for an answer to this question, all that I could find is answers that are years old. most answers led me to knowing that vimeo does not allow video streaming on android native unless you are a pro user. My question is, is there a change to this policy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java  - quoting the readme: `User must be PRO or higher (or the app must have the "can access owner's video files" capability).`

Comment: follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Answer (score 0):

No: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links

> Vimeo Premium, Business, and PRO members have access to the direct links to their converted video files, which can be used to download or play videos hosted on Vimeo through a third-party player or web page.