# Cordova Vimeo No Full Screen Android

Tags: android, cordova, vimeo

We just noticed that our Vimeo videos do not open in full screen anymore when the play button is tapped on Android devices and there is no way to make the video full screen either. Full screen does still work in iOS though. We even went back and tested an older version of the Cordova based app and those no longer opened in full screen so it seems to be an issue with Vimeo.

I've tried doing some searching via StackOverflow and Google but have not been able to find anything that has helped. Has anyone else had this issue? None of our code has changed when it comes to videos and this used to work. Like I said previously, it still works on iOS. I would say it's an Android issue however, it doesn't work on an older Android OS anymore either with an older version of our app so it seems that it's a Vimeo issue.

Thank you!

Comment: follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348